# How to convert columns of a dataframe to list with different lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data frame with columns of different lengths. It looks like this:

```
Croptypes   VariableInputs   FixedInputs
barley      fertilizer       land
rapeseed                     labor
wheat                        capital
```

when I list the elements from the columns by the following codes:

```
Croptypes = list(df['Croptypes'])
VariableInputs = list(df['VariableInputs'])
```

I get this results.

```
['barley', 'rapeseed', 'wheat']
['fertilizer', nan, nan]
```

How can I tell "list" not to list the empty cells?

I expect:

```
['barley', 'rapeseed', 'wheat']
['fertilizer']
```

Comment: Use `list(df['VariableInputs'].dropna())` to remove null values.

Comment: (Off topic, but stylistically, `snake_case` should be used for variables in Python, with possible exceptions for mathematical vector variables like `L` or `Y3`. `TitleCase` should be used for class names. Defying conventions will only work to confuse everyone and hurt your chances of collaboratively finding problems.)

Comment: `[x for x in df['FixedInputs'] if pd.notna(x)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dropna` and `tolist`:

```
>>> df['VariableInputs'].dropna().tolist()
['fertilizer']
>>>
```

Or for every column:

```
print({k: v.dropna().tolist() for k, v in df.to_dict('s').items()})
```

Output:

```
{'Croptypes': ['barley', 'rapeseed', 'wheat'], 'VariableInputs': ['fertilizer'], 'FixedInputs': ['land', 'labor', 'capital']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary for each column with values as list as:

```
d = {col:df[col].dropna().tolist() for col in df}

d
{'Croptypes': ['barley', 'rapeseed', 'wheat'],
 'VariableInputs': ['fertilizer'],
 'FixedInputs': ['land', 'labor', 'capital']}
```